# Constructor of class extending Float32Array called again after object creation

Tags: javascript, firefox, ecmascript-6

I am attempting to write a set of classes which extend `Float32Array`, but when it runs in Firefox, the constructor for the class gets called again when I try to use the object.

This script demonstrates the error:

```
"use strict";

class ARRAYty extends Float32Array {
    constructor(...a) {
        console.log('ARRAYty', ...a);
        super(10);
    }
}

var v = new ARRAYty();
console.log('V constructed');
console.log(v);
console.log(v);
```

In Firefox the console displays

```
ARRAYty
V constructed
ARRAYty ArrayBuffer{} 0 10
Float32Array(10) [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
ARRAYty ArrayBuffer{} 0 10
Float32Array(10) [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

Every time I refer to `v` after its initialisation, the constructor is called again (with three arguments passed to it that appear to be the internal components of the `Float32Array` object. The constructor should only be called once, when `new ARRAYty()` is called.

Can anyone see why this is happening? Is it a bug/quirk in Firefox's implementation, or is there something I should do differently to avoid this?

This does not happen in Chrome or Edge, and it does not happen if I replace `Float32Array` with `Array`.

Comment: Maybe the console is using `map` or something that creates a new array? Use `console.trace()` instead of `console.log()` to see.